# Get access to later versions of GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, version, textures

I was making a shader with GLSL so I could apply texture arrays to a cube when I ran into an issue. The issue was that `layout` wasn't supported in the version I was using. Easy fix, use a later version, but the problem with that was that I don't have support for later versions that support `layout`. I was wondering, is it possible to get support for later versions of GLSL, and if so, how would I do such a thing?

This is my current GLSL code for applying textures
Vertex Shader:

```c
#version 130
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```c
#version 130
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2DArray texture;
uniform index;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture, vec3(TexCoord, index));
}
```

Result of running:

```py
print(glGetString(GL_VENDOR))
print(glGetString(GL_RENDERER))
print(glGetString(GL_VERSION))
print(glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION))
```

Intel Open Source Technology Center

Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile

3.0 Mesa 18.3.6

1.30

Comment: *"I don't have support for later versions [...]"* - Why? What is your hardware? How do you create the OpenGL Context?

Comment: I added current hardware

Comment: Mesa supports OpenGL 3.3 core profile on Sandy Bridge just fine, it does not support compatibility profile though, so you end up with GL 3.0 if you request a legacy context.

Comment: How do I make sure I'm requesting the latest context?